# I got error:Repository is not clean. Please commit or stash any changes before updating

Tags: angular, angular6, angular8

I want update my project angular6 to angular8.

First:  run `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest` (this code is ok).

Second: run `ng update @angular/cli @angular/core`.
And I got this error:

> Repository is not clean.  Please commit or stash any changes before
>   updating.

This is simple angular6 project, just have some basic controller.

when I run `ng update @angular/cli @angular/core`. I got the error.

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^6.1.7",
  "@angular/common": "^6.1.7",
  "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.7",
  "@angular/core": "^6.1.7",
  "@angular/forms": "^6.1.7",
  "@angular/http": "^6.1.7",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.7",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.7",
  "@angular/router": "^6.1.7",
  "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^3.2.0",
  "@types/bootstrap": "^3.3.37",
  "@types/jquery": "^3.3.0",
  "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
  "core-js": "^2.4.1",
  "jquery": "^3.3.1",
  "rxjs": "^6.3.2",
  "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0-rc.0",
  "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.8.0",
  "@angular/cli": "^6.2.1",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.7",
  "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.7",
  "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
  "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
  "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
  "codelyzer": "^4.4.4",
  "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
  "karma": "~2.0.0",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
  "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
  "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
  "popper.js": "^1.14.4",
  "protractor": "~5.1.2",
  "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
  "tslint": "~5.9.1",
  "typescript": "~2.9.2"
}
```

Wow, What should I do?,I stop there whole day.

Comment: hit `git status` and check is there any file changes

Answer (score 0):

You need to commit your changes in git before you do an update, this was you'll see all of the changes that ng update has made. Just do:

```
git commit
```

Then retry your upgrade.

Comment: What result do you get if you do: git diff

Comment: o,thanks for u help!!  i solved the problem,,,,,,,，，，
Because your method inspired me